# try except not working with python ggplot

Tags: python, try-except, python-ggplot

I am debugging a problem in some python `ggplot` code.  So that I could see if my efforts (which I expect are coming from the underlying data frame) are working, I tried to wrap the problem code in a `try/except` statement.  However, when I run the Python 2.7 Jupyter cell the code is in, if I take off the `try/except`, it throws an error.  Put try/except back on, and the cell simply executes with no output of any kind.

Does `ggplot` not work with `try/except`?  Or is there something I need to do differently to this code so the interaction will react as expected?

**Problem Code:**

```
try:
    ggplot(aes(x='Date', y='Price', color='Daily'), data=googleHiLoPlotData) \
        + geom_density() 
except Exception as ee:
    print(ee)
    print(type(ee))
```

**Error it only throws if I remove `try/except` and take out the indenting:**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'long'
```

I have copied the 'try/except' block to another cell and verified that if I replace the entire `ggplot` line to something else that will throw an error, it works and then prints the error and error type as expected.  So the problem seems to be something about this specific code within the block.  Any ideas what is going on here, and how to make it throw the error correctly) with the `ggplot` line?

Version Info:  Python 2.7, ggplot 0.11.5, Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in creating this question (and doing a little investigation of the issue myself), I may have uncovered a bug in either `ggplot` or python for this specific interaction.

Simply changing the x value in the `ggplot` line to `'Something Stupid'`, the `try-except` error then gets reported and printed as per the `except` portion of the block.

However - Anaconda was installed using version 4.2.  Until I rule out the possibility that something needs an upgrade, this bug should not be reported yet.  It is worth noting in case anyone else encounters the same problem.